# How to remove \r\n in string and make string to array

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tr

i have string get from api like below

```
/patha/pathb/pathc\r\n/patha/pathb/pathc\r\n/patha/pathb/pathc
```

How to split /patha/pathb/pathc to element in array ?

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems; so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `your_array=($(sed 's/\\r\\n/ /g' <<< $your_string))`.

You can also use `echo $your string | sed. . . .` if you prefer that. Either works fine. echo is probably more readable and more implemented everywhere.

Edit: if those paths include space, this will be a better option -

```
your_array=($(sed 's/ /~_~/g; s/\\r\\n/ /g' <<< $your_string))
i=0
for x in ${your_array[@]}; do your_array[$i]=$(sed 's/~_~/ /g' <<< $x) && let i++; done
```

I used `~_~` to not override any existing characters.

Edit2: a much better way is this -

```
temp=$(sed 's|\\r||g; s|\\|\\\\|g' <<< $your_string)
ifs=$IFS
IFS="
"
your_array=($(for x in $(eval echo -e $temp); do echo $x; done))
IFS=$ifs
```

Comment: I think for this task, a `your_array=($(dos2unix <<<$your_string))` would be more clear, but both solutions would break, if one of the path components has embedded spaces, because word splitting occurs on space and newlines alike.

Comment: @user1934428 I've updated the answer. Although, it seems bit tedious. I'm open for other ideas.

Comment: I think the second approach is better. The first would fail, if a path already contains `~_~`. As for another idea, have a look as the response by anubhava to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666321/how-to-put-environment-variable-in-array/60666597?noredirect=1#comment107334204_60666597) question. Though I can not get it to work, maybe because I'm unsing the Cygwin environment, the approach looks promising.

Comment: @user1934428 I too think the second one's more promising. About the other answer you linked to, the problem is that they have a specific delimiter character, that too not something that most utilities consider a special character. Also, they can use regexes to search inside while we can't because of the randomness of a file/directory name.

Comment: In addition to white space issues, that will fail for various values of your_string given  the contents of various directories you execute it from since you are asking the shell to interpret it by removing the standard double quotes that should be present around all variable expansions by default. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. The 2nd script will also remove any `\r`s that are part of the file names, not just those at the end of each file name (in the context of `\r\n`) and, I suspect, exposes you to malicious code execution courtesy of the `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ str='/patha/pathb/pathc\r\n/patha/pathb/pathc\r\n/patha/pathb/pathc'
$ readarray -t -d $'\n' arr < <(sed 's/\\r\\n/\n/g' <<< "$str")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="/patha/pathb/pathc" [1]="/patha/pathb/pathc" [2]="/patha/pathb/pathc")
```

The above will work for any values of `str` except newlines in the paths - figure out how to use `\0` (NUL) instead of `\n` as the path separator if that's an issue for you.

Not sure why I couldn't get this to work with NUL as the separator:

```
$ readarray -t -d $'\0' arr < <(sed 's/\\r\\n/\0/g' <<< "$str")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]=$'/patha/pathb/pathc\\r\\n/patha/pathb/pathc\\r\\n/patha/pathb/pathc\n')
```

nor some variation of these to work so I could avoid calling sed:

```
$ echo "${str//\\r\\n/\n}"
/patha/pathb/pathcn/patha/pathb/pathcn/patha/pathb/pathc

$ echo "${str//\\r\\n/"$'\n'"}"
/patha/pathb/pathc$'\n'/patha/pathb/pathc$'\n'/patha/pathb/pathc

$ echo "${str//\\r\\n/"$(printf $'\n')"}"
/patha/pathb/pathc/patha/pathb/pathc/patha/pathb/pathc
```

Comment: Maybe adding `--null-data` to `sed` would help?

Comment: @user1934428 no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
:>arr=$(echo "/patha/pathb/pathc\r\n/patha/pathb/pathc\r\n/patha/pathb/pathc" | tr '\\r\\n' '\n'  | grep -v '^$')
:>for i in $arr
> do
> echo $i
> done
/patha/pathb/pathc
/patha/pathb/pathc
/patha/pathb/pathc
:>
```

Using `tr`

Comment: This approach won't work. `tr` considers its arguments individual characters, not a string. It'll give him unpredictable results each time.

Comment: It'll also fail if the paths contain white space or globbing characters.

Comment: @anotherusername Could you please provide a example. Apologies but I didn't got the point

Comment: @DigvijayS As an example - `echo 'this is a line\nthis is another line' | tr '\\n' ' '` the output of this won't be 'this is a line this is another line'. It'll be "this is a li e this is a other li e".

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with a locally scoped IFS.

```
my_str=$'a\r\nb\r\nc\r\n'
IFS=$'\r\n' arr=($(echo "$my_str"))

printf "%s" ${arr[0]} | hexdump -C
00000000  61                                                |a|
00000001
```

Try again after removing `\r` from the local IFS to see the difference.

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(echo "$my_str"))

printf "%s" ${arr[0]} | hexdump -C
00000000  61 0d                                             |a.|
00000002
```