# How to put environment variable in Array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ksh

DIR1, DIR2, .... DIRN are coming from environment variables that contains some directory path.
example

```
export DIR1="/users/abcd"
export DIR2="/users/abcd/xyz"
.
.
.
```

How do i know that how many DIR_ is in environment variable and put all these in the following array

```
arr=(DIR1 DIR2 ... . . DIRN)
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#arr[@]} ] 
do
      cd ${arr[$i]}
      i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: It looks like DIR1 is not coming from the environment at all, but is being explicitly set in your script.

Comment: yes @WilliamPursell there is a groovy script which takes input directory as map and export it in the shell script.

Comment: Wouldn't it shows up in env variable?

Comment: The variables DIR1, etc. will be in the environment of any subshells, and perhaps that's what you're interested in.

Comment: If you want the variable *names* in the array (as you have now), you need indirection parameter expansion to get the actual directory, `cd "${!arr[$i]}"`. If you want the *directories* in the array, you need `arr=("$DIR1" "$DIR2 ... "$DIRN")`.

Comment: I'm surprised no answer yet present here uses bash's built-in ability to iterate over variable names that start with a fixed prefix. If there's still no such answer in 10 hours or so, I'll add one then.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy eagerly waiting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cases when environment variables may contain newlines in their values you can use this script that uses gnu versions of `printenv` and `awk`.

```
mapfile -t arr < <(printenv -0 | awk -v RS='\0' -F= '/^DIR/{print $1}')
```

Then check your array content as:

```
declare -p arr
```

Comment: Your answer looks reasonable to me, but when I try this approach, I get (most likely from the process redirection) the error message _bash: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory_ . I get this even if I replace the whole pipe by an innocent `echo 123`. Any idea, why? Using the Cygwin version of _bash 4.4.12(3)_

Comment: Hi @anubhava,
i am getting this.
-ksh: mapfile: not found [No such file or directory]
looks like mapfile command doesn't working. however ```printenv -0 | awk -v RS='\0' -F= '/^DIR/{print $1}'``` this returns the correct result.

Comment: No no you cannot do that in `ksh`. You must use `bash` as per your tag in question. Run `bash` first and then run this command in answer.

Comment: If you want to use ksh then use `arr=($(printenv -0 | awk -v RS='\0' -F= '/^S/{print $1}'))`

Comment: @anubhava : The error message disappeared after a reboot. I have no idea what weird value I had in my environment to cause **that** effect which I had observed. All I can say now is that your solution now seems to work like a charm.

Comment: @satishkumar: I find it a bit odd, that you expicitly asked for a _bash_ solution (given that you used the _bash_ tag) in your question, and now, in a comment, request also one for ksh. Maybe after this, you want to have one which works in Zsh, and one for Posix shell. If you need solutions for several shells, either write this explicitly in your comment, or better yet, ask separate questions for the respective shells.

Comment: @anubhava you mean ```arr=($(printenv -0 | awk -v RS='\0' -F= '/^DIR/{print $1}'))``` ?

Comment: @anubhava when i trying to ```cd ${arr[$i]}``` it says ```DIR1``` not found. it is not taking dir PATH. it takes literal ```DIR1```.

Comment: Anyway if you use `bash` then you can use: `cd "${!arr[$i]}"`

Comment: @anubhava My apologies.  I am quite new to this platform.

Answer (score 2):

`"${!prefix@}"` expands to the list of variable names that start with `prefix`. In present circumstances, this can be used as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || { echo "This must be run with bash, not /bin/sh" >&2; exit 1; }

arr=( )
for varname in "${!DIR@}"; do
  [[ $varname =~ ^DIR[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue ## skip DIRSTACK or other names that don't match
  arr+=( "${!varname}" )
done
```

Comment: @Matthieu, thank you for reminding me. I quite forgot about the question this morning, and wouldn't have come back to it if not for your message.

Answer (score 1):

```
printenv   |  awk -F'=' '{if ($0 ~ /^DIR/) print $2; }'
```

Demo :

```
:-:export DIR1="/users/abcd"
:-:export DIR2="/users/abcd"
:-:export DIR4="/usasders/abcd"
:-:printenv   |  awk -F'=' '{if ($0 ~ /^DIR/) print $2; }'
/usasders/abcd
/users/abcd
/users/abcd
:-:
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25600722)

Comment: @veben I have edited the post and added Demo as well. What is the asnwer you are lookin for ?

Answer (score 0):

My answer refers to the **written** part of your question, where you ask for **environment** variables, since from the example you gave, it is not clear whether the variables in question are really environment variables or mere shell variables.

Since `printenv` gives you a list of environment variables in the form of *NAME=VALUE* denotations, you can do a

```
arr=($(printenv|grep '^DIR[0-9]'|cut -f 1 -d =))
```

The `grep` picks the lines starting with *DIR*, followed by at least one digit. Adjust the pattern to your needs.

The `cut` picks just the left part of the equal sign, i.e. the name.

This solution assumes that you don't have environment variables which contain embedded newlines. In this case, I suggest to use a programming language which gives you a list of environment variables you can loop over. *Perl*, *Ruby* or *Java* would do.

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). Populating an array this way allowed unintended string substitution and glob expansion to modify your values.

Comment: @user1934428, one certainly can reliably list and retrieve environment and other variables in bash, even if their values contain newlines. f/e, one can use `compgen -v` to get *only* the names with no values, and then [indirect expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) to retrieve the value for each name.

Comment: ...or, on Linux, one can use something like `while IFS= read -r -d '' vardef; do name=${vardef%%=*}; value=${vardef#*=}; printf '%q=%q\n' "$name" "$value"; done </proc/self/environ` to iterate over environment variables set at process initialization time only.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Thank you for your helpful comments. Not really related to the OP's question, but Do you, by chance, know whether something like `compgen -v` can be done in Zsh too? My Zsh (5.5.1) does not have the internal command compgen.

Comment: @user1934428 No, I can't speak to zsh -- gave it up more than 15 years ago when I realized that it was getting me into habits that resulted in buggy code whenever I needed to write scripts for a non-zsh shell; in the intervening time I've forgotten pretty much everything I knew about it. If you can't find a zsh-specific answer already in the knowledge base, feel free to ask a new question tagged for zsh specifically.